# Bubble Sort in a structed list that are filled by a csv file

Tags: c++, linked-list, bubble-sort

I load a .csv file that fill my struct

```
typedef struct list TList;
    struct list {
        int index;
        char data;
        TList* prox;
    };
```

How can I do a bubble sort in my list ?

I tried the follow

```
void bubble(TList *list, int siz) {
    int c = 0;
    int x, y, temp;

    for (x = (siz - 1); x >= 0; x--) {
        c++;
        for (y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
            c++;
            if (list->index[y - 1] > list->index[y]) {
                temp = list->index[y - 1];
                list->index[y - 1] = list->index[y];
                list->index[y] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nNeeded Steps: %i\n", c);
}
```

I think this is because the `list->index[y]`.  It's like a table in a database... at position 0 (index), I have the data, and the pointer to the next node.   With `list->index[..]` I want to pass the position and get that node, like an array.  It is a linked-list and `prox` needs to point to the next node. I filled my list with the data that came from a .csv file, and the `list->prox` points to the next node.

Comment: `list->index[...]` makes no sense.  `index` is an `int`, not an array.  What are you attempting to do here?

Comment: what does `index[y - 1]` mean, when `index` is declared as `int`?

Comment: No...i think this is because the list->index[y].

Comment: What happened?  What did you expect to happen?  Is this a home-rolled linked-list?  Is this C++ or C (looks like C to me)?  Please put as much information as possible in the question.

Comment: It's like a table in a database...at position 0 (index), I have the data, and the pointer to the next register

Comment: index is an int, it has no positions.  Tables have no registers.  What?

Comment: at list->index[..] I wanna pass the position. Like an array.

Comment: If this is a linked-list, know that linked-lists are not randomly addressable, which is what you're trying to do.  If it's like an array, what does `prox` point at?

Comment: Is a linked-list and prox need to point to the next register. I filled my list with the data thar come from the .csv file, and the list->prox point to the next register

Comment: linked lists cannot be addressable like arrays are.  You have to traverse the list to find the element you want.

Comment: I'm not a good developer in C, but do yoi have some samples how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STL provides nice built-in sort algorithm. check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/

Comment: Yes, that's part of the C++ standard library

Comment: Ok, but how can I do to pass a list ?

Comment: If what you want to do is sort numbers in the file. Parse  out numbers and store them in a vector, over which call STL sort. I think you can get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct list TList;
struct list {
    int index;
    char data;
    TList* prox;

    //give the list an [] like an array
    char& operator[](int index) {
        TList* cur = this;
        while(cur->index != index) {
            if (cur->prox == NULL)
                throw std::exception("INVALID INDEX");
            cur = cur->prox;
        }
        return cur->data;
    }
};
```

This will let you use the index operator on your linked list kinda like an array.

```
        if ((*list)[y - 1] > (*list)[y]) {
```

Comment: Which include I have to do to implements that?

Answer (score 0):

Your inner if is incorrect (both the if conditional as well as the the swap).
You want to swap the entire TList, not just the indexes of each TList. For example, if you have two TLists like this:

```
TList[0]       TList[1]
Index1         Index0
"Data for 1"   "Data for 0"
```

after swapping, you want

```
TList[0]       TList[1]
Index0         Index1
"Data for 0"   "Data for 1"
```

Instead, your inner loop does this:

```
TList[0]       TList[1]
Index0         Index1
"Data for 1"   "Data for 0"
```

But it doesnt do this actually, because your if conditional doesn't work as Mooing Duck pointed out in the comments. Hint: You don't want to change anything in any of the TLists, you just want to change where they are relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Why oh why would you want to use a bubble sort? It's the classic example of an algorithm that's essentially *always* the wrong choice!

If you're doing this in real code, just use a standard collection (`std::list` if you insist on a linked list, probably `std::vector` if you're being sane), and then use `std::sort` to do the sorting.

If you're doing this for something like homework, and really must use your own list structure and a horrible algorithm, then you'd implement your iteration and comparison using pointers instead of subscripts, so your comparison would be something like

```
if (pos->index > pos->next->index)
    /* swap items */
```

You'll (probably) also want to base at least your inner loop on pointer operations instead of integers and indexing -- its increment operation will probably be something like `pos=pos->next`.

Also note that with a singly linked list, it's difficult to do a swap involving the current node, so you frequently want to consider the next node and the one after that (at least when you can -- I.e., not dealing with the first node).